# Using ModelBuilder to update feature line length

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geometric-network

I maintain a network of lines (geometric network) in an enterprise geodatabase and would like to automate the updating of a field after I complete my editing. The goal is to run the script nightly on a server to update the field.

The field I'd like to update represents a custom length value (miles) that is different then the shape length value.

Is it possible to create a model using ModelBuilder that will allow the calculation and updating of this field?

What tools would you use in ModelBuilder to calculate geometry and update the rows?

It does not matter if all rows are recalculated nightly even if they are not edited.

This is my first attempt in trying to build a model that addresses this type of update.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What does your model do far look like?